# How to restrict a property's type to predefined two types (UIColor or CAGradientLayer)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to strictly restrict property `filling` to types either `UIColor` or `CAGradientLayer`. I could make `UIColor` and `CAGradientLayer` conform to some protocol to achieve this but then any type can be conformed to that protocol which is not desired. What is the best way to achieve the following?

```
class A {
   var filling: (UIColor or CAGradientLayer)
   var width: CGFloat
}

class B {
   var arrayOfA: [A]

   init(arrayOfA: [A] {
       self.arrayOfA = arrayOfA
   }
}

let bObj1 = B(arrayOfA: [A(filling: UIColor.white, width: 5),
                         A(filling: CAGradientLayer(), width: 10)]) //allowed

let bObj2 = B(arrayOfA: [A(filling: UIColor.white, width: 5),
                         A(filling: AnyRandomType(), width: 10)]) //not allowed
```

Comment: Does `A` check the type of `filling`, and cast `filling` to the right type? It would be very helpful to know how `A` makes use of `filling`.

Comment: @Sweeper Somewhere in class B, I'll be checking the type of `filling` and accordingly "filling" the background of some view. So, if it is `UIColor`, I'll set `backgroundColor` or if it is `CAGradientLayer` I'll be adding that layer as sublayer and will act as background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great use case of enum with associated values:

```
enum Filling {
    case pureColor(UIColor)
    case gradient(CAGradientLayer)
}
```

You can use `Filling` as the type of `filling`:

```
var filling: Filling

// ...

let bObj1 = B(arrayOfA: [A(filling: .pureColor(.white), width: 5),
                         A(filling: .gradient(CAGradientLayer()), width: 10)]
```

To check the type of filling, use a switch statement:

```
switch filling {
    case .pureColor(let color):
        ...
    case .gradient(let layer):
        ...
}
```