# Swift Generic Type Constraint with or operator

Tags: swift, generics, type-constraints

I am trying to make protocol which generic types are limited to types can be saved to UserDefaults.

Is it possible to have type constraints with either conforms to a specific type or another specific type?

For example code below works.

```
public protocol UserDefaultsRequestType {

    associatedtype ValueToSet where ValueToSet == URL

    var valueToSet: ValueToSet { get }
}
```

Something I want achieve is like the blow

```
public protocol UserDefaultsRequestType {

    // Value should either be a type URL, String or Bool
    associatedtype ValueToSet where ValueToSet == URL || ValueToSet == String || ValueToSet == Bool

    var valueToSet: ValueToSet { get }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how limiting the choice of an associated type to just three types can be useful?

Comment: Those are just examples.  I am trying to make protocol which generic types are limited to types can be saved to UserDefaults

Comment: What I mean is this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so it will be very helpful if you can explain what you _actually_ want to do.

Comment: I provided more detail

Comment: Okay, how about using something like the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62482935/5133585) instead of associated types?

Comment: This pretty much solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look more like a XOR, since a variable can't be an `URL` and a `String` at the same time but to answer you question you **can't** do it!

But I think you already know that since the compiler probably told you :

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

But if you want `ValueToSet` to be either `URL`, `String` or `Bool` It should be because these 3 types have something that you need in common, and it means a conformance to a `protocol` or `inheritance` from a base class.

The 3 types you gave conforms

- CKRecordValueProtocol
- CustomReflectable
- CustomStringConvertible
- CVarArg
- Decodable
- Encodable
- Equatable
- Hashable
- MLDataValueConvertible

So let's say you want to be able to use them as keys in a `Dictionary` you could write :

```
associatedtype ValueToSet where ValueToSet: Hashable
```

Meaning that `ValueToSet` can be **ANY** type conforming to `Hashable`.

But since you seem to be working with `UserDefaults` and it's public methods to set default values are *not* using `protocols` nor classes.

eg:

```
func set(_ url: URL?, forKey defaultName: String)
```

This approach won't get you far, the one proposed by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62482935/5133585) is probably best for you.